# PostFix Evaluation Result Error

Tags: java

```
public static int postFixEvaluation(int[] numValues, String postfix){
            Stack<Integer> evaluateStack = new Stack<Integer>();
            char[] chars = postfix.toCharArray();
            int length = chars.length;
            int currentNumValue =0; 
            int currentLocation =0; 
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
                char currentChar = chars[i];
            if(Character.isLetter(currentChar))//checks to see if character is a letter 
            {
                //replace all letters with values 
                currentLocation = charToNum(currentChar);//this retrieves the location of specific letter
                currentNumValue= (numValues[currentLocation]);//retrieves the value of that location
                evaluateStack.push(currentNumValue);//get the number value of that variable and push it on stack
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evaluateStack.toArray()));//prints out stack elements 

            }

                else if(isOperator(currentChar)){//checks if character is an operator 
                    switch(currentChar){//switches evaluation according to operator 
                    case '+': evaluateStack.push(evaluateStack.pop() + evaluateStack.pop()); break;
                    case '*': evaluateStack.push(evaluateStack.pop() * evaluateStack.pop()); break;
                    case '-': evaluateStack.push(evaluateStack.pop() - evaluateStack.pop()); break;
                    case '/': evaluateStack.push(evaluateStack.pop() / evaluateStack.pop()); break;
                    }
                }

            }
            if (!evaluateStack.isEmpty()) //as long as the stack is not empty 
                return evaluateStack.pop();//returns the result
            else
                return 0;//if it is empty returns zero 
        }
```

Input:

```
C = -13
X = 5
H = 25
D = 4
$PART2
C-(B+(C+(A-E)))-X
(D+C)-(H*X-C)
(A-H)/(D+B)
A*H+C Infix: C-(B+(C+(A-E)))-X
Postfix: CBCAE-++-X-
[-13]
[-13, 2]
[-13, 2, -13]
[-13, 2, -13, 1]
[-13, 2, -13, 1, 5]
[6, 5]
Result: -1**Result should be: -3**

Infix: (D+C)-(H*X-C)
Postfix: DC+HX*C--
[4]
[4, -13]
[-9, 25]
[-9, 25, 5]
[-9, 125, -13]
Result: -129 **Result should be: -147**

Infix: (A-H)/(D+B)
Postfix: AH-DB+/
[1]
[1, 25]
[24, 4]
[24, 4, 2]
Result: 0**Result should be: -4**


Infix: A*H+C
Postfix: AH*C+
[1]
[1, 25]
[25, -13]
Result: 12**Correct Result**
```

I can't figure out why my postEvaluation won't produce the correct output. If anyone could please help! I have commented extensively throughout my code so please let me know if I can clarify anything. Thanks!

Comment: so you have logical errors? have you tried to play around with you debugger?

Comment: Yes thats why I've been printing out the contents of the stack to be able to see what it is calculating at every step. I still cant figure it out.

Comment: Jim you should not remove your original code from your question. By removing it your making the question and the answers unusable for future users having the same or an equal problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont have a computer at hand, only an old school paper and pen, my phone and some knowledge about the shunting-yard algorithm.

I think your error is this (only tested on paper):

Instead of evaluating A-E you are doing an E-A. The same goes for the other operators.

Wrong:

```
evaluateStack.push(evaluateStack.pop() + evaluateStack.pop());
```

Correct:

```
//Don't change pop order here!
int righthand = evaluateStack.pop();
int lefthand = evaluateStack.pop();

evaluateStack.push(lefthand + righthand);
```

This is what I corrected it to:

```
public static int postFixEvaluation(int[] numValues, String postfix){
    Stack<Integer> evaluateStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    char[] chars = postfix.toCharArray();
    int length = chars.length;
    int currentNumValue =0;
    int currentLocation =0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        char currentChar = chars[i];

        //checks to see if character is a letter
        if (Character.isLetter(currentChar)){
            //replace all letters with values 
            currentLocation = charToNum(currentChar);//this retrieves the location of specific letter
            currentNumValue = (numValues[currentLocation]);//retrieves the value of that location
            evaluateStack.push(currentNumValue);//get the number value of that variable and push it on stack
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evaluateStack.toArray()));//prints out stack elements 
        }


        //checks if character is an operator 
        if (isOperator(currentChar)){
            int righthand = evaluateStack.pop();
            int lefthand = evaluateStack.pop();
            switch (currentChar){
            //switches evaluation according to operator 
                case '+': evaluateStack.push(lefthand + righthand); break;
                case '*': evaluateStack.push(lefthand * righthand); break;
                case '-': evaluateStack.push(lefthand - righthand); break;
                case '/': evaluateStack.push(lefthand / righthand); break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!evaluateStack.isEmpty()){ //as long as the stack is not empty
        return evaluateStack.pop();//returns the result
    } else {
        return 0; //if it is empty returns zero 
    }
}
```

Some additional tips: You should have added your helper functions and what the code does in terms of algorithms to your question. This will probably attract more people to answer your question.

Comment: So how would I apply this to my code? I understand the logic behind it but since I am replacing the letters in the expression with integer values how would I reference it in terms of righthand and lefthand variables?

Comment: I tried to implement it and said my stack was empty

Comment: If implemented correctly the same amount of variables are popped from the stack. How does your new debug output look?

Comment: It keeps giving me an empty stack error. I can't figure out why it doesnt let me pop the numbers that i placed in it

Comment: I have added it in to your post! @Rolf

Comment: You have added it to the wrong place you should have placed it in the operator switch part.